# Select Specific Rows in Deedle

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

I have a deedle data frame, called df, with one of the columns named `TimeSpent`.

I would like to keep the rows, which have values for `TimeSpent` greater than a specific TimeSpan (e.g. 30 minutes). 
I could only manage to keep the rows with a specific `TimeSpan (30 min)` by using `FilterRowsBy()`

```
df = df.FilterRowsBy<int, string, TimeSpan>("TimeSpent", new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
```

How do you filter a deedle data frame for a certain range?

UPDATE: So, I decided to try to sort the deedle frame by `TimeSpan` first, and then slice it.

```
Frame<TimeSpan, string> dfTest = df.IndexRows<TimeSpan>("TimeSpent").SortRowsByKey();
var dfTest2 = dfTest.Rows.After(twentyMin);
```

And as a result I get a new data frame that is type `<TimeSpan, ObjectSeries<System.String>>`, but I need to convert this data frame to `<TimeSpan, String>`, and I do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using linq to sort the data frame, after creating a new index by `TimeSpan`.

```
Frame<TimeSpan, string> dfResult =
    df.IndexRows<TimeSpan>("TimeSpent")
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Key > new Timespan(0, 20, 0));
```

Comment: When indexing by rows, '"TimeSpent"' has to be unique, otherwise an error is thrown.