# Deedle Frame From Database, What is the Schema?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, f#, deedle

I am new to Deedle, and in documentation I cant find how to solve my problem.

I bind an SQL Table to a Deedle Frame using the following code:

```
namespace teste

open FSharp.Data.Sql
open Deedle
open System.Linq

module DatabaseService =

    [<Literal>]
    let connectionString = "Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=*******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=****";

    type bd = SqlDataProvider<
                ConnectionString = connectionString,
                DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER >

    type Database() =

        static member contextDbo() =
            bd.GetDataContext().Dbo

        static member acAgregations() =
            Database.contextDbo().AcAgregations |> Frame.ofRecords

        static member acBusyHourDefinition() =
            Database.contextDbo().AcBusyHourDefinition
            |> Frame.ofRecords "alternative_reference_table_scan", "formula"]

        static member acBusyHourDefinitionFilterByTimeAgregationTipe(value:int) = 
            Database.acBusyHourDefinition()
            |> Frame.getRows
```

These things are working properly becuse I can't understand the Data Frame Schema, for my surprise, this is not a representation of the table.

My question is:

how can I access my database elements by Rows instead of Columns (columns is the Deedle Default)? I Thied what is showed in documentation, but unfortunatelly, the columns names are not recognized, as is in [the CSV example in Deedle Website](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/features.html).

Comment: So you managed to connect the SQL Server to the type provider I see. You should also explore [SqlClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/). Regarding your question it's a bit difficult to say without an example of the input/output and your expectation. In fact, most of the functionality of Deedle is on **Rows**. So when I work with columns I often end up transposing the frame. Is it possible that you haven't assigned an index column? Say something like: `let df = df.IndexRows<DateTime>("DateIndex")`.

Comment: In fact what I need to know is simple: Deedle append an index to enumerate the rows, when I try to access Rows I need to refer for this indez, but I don't know what is.

Comment: You can get the index: `df.RowIndex` and `df.RowIndex.Keys`.

Answer (score 1):

With `Frame.ofRecords` you can extract the table into a dataframe and then operate on its rows or columns. In this case I have a very simple table. This is for SQL Server but I assume MySQL will work the same. If you provide more details in your question the solution can narrowed down.

This is the table, indexed by ID, which is Int64:

[image]

You can work with the rows or the columns:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#load @"..\..\FSLAB\packages\FsLab\FsLab.fsx"
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
#endif

//open FSharp.Data
//open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Deedle

[<Literal>]
let connectionString1 = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\userName\Documents\tes.sdf.mdf"

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<connectionString1>
let dbx = dbSchema.GetDataContext()

let table1 = dbx.Table_1


query { for row in table1 do
        select row} |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x.ID < 10L) |> Seq.toList
// check if we can connect to the DB.

let df = table1 |> Frame.ofRecords // pull the table into a df
let df = df.IndexRows<System.Int64>("ID") // if you need an index
df.GetRows(2L) // Get the second row, but this can be any kind of index/key 
df.["Number"].GetSlice(Some 2L, Some 5L) // get  the 2nd to 5th row from the Number column
```

Will get you the following output:

```
val it : Series<System.Int64,float> = 
2 -> 2 

> 
val it : Series<System.Int64,float> = 
2 -> 2 
3 -> 3 
4 -> 4 
5 -> 5
```

Depending on what you're trying to do [Selecting Specific Rows in Deedle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060305/select-specific-rows-in-deedle) might also work.

**Edit**

From your comment you appear to be working with some large table. Depending on how much memory you have and how large the table you still might be able to load it. If not these are some of things you can do in increasing complexity:

1. Use a `query { }` [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/query-expressions-%5Bfsharp%5D/) like above to narrow the dataset on the database server and convert just part of the result into a dataframe. You can do quite complex transformations so you might not even need the dataframe in the end. This is basically Linq2Sql.
2. Use [lazy loading](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/lazysource.html/) in Deedle. This works with series so you can get a few series and reassemble a dataframe.
3. Use [Big Deedle](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle.BigDemo/) which is designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Your answer is interesting but keep my problem, if you see, you are interesting over rows before make a data frame, the problem is: I will have to read all the table, but it's big. The way I did append  the table reference in the frame, so, accessing the frame (making the various filters and etc) is done while operating, no need to read the database and keep in memory.

Comment: Do you know how may I do this direct reference from a table like yours?

Comment: @AndréClaudino Are you sure that's a problem? I am actually not iterating over the rows, the `query { ... }` was just an example. No you might be right, and dumping lots of data into a df might be problematic. I will test with some large table. But in that case you can use Linq2Sql (aka query expressions) or maybe [Lazy Loading](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/lazysource.html/). We can discuss in [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)

Comment: When linking a database table as link frame, what I understand, is it will lazy loading data. Am I wrong? I tried the chat, but it seems not working  in my phone.

Comment: When linking a database table as link frame, what I understand, is it will lazy loading data. Am I wrong? I tried the chat, but it seems not working  in my phone.

Comment: @AndréClaudino No worries about the chat. you get lazy loading in Linq. Once you get into the realm of Deedle, It's possible that deedle will load the whole table, hence it's better to operate first on a subset, and then dump the result into a dataframe. That's why I referenced the Lazy Loading link. That might work for you. Also I commented on your index question in the comment.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this way and come back with the results.